# Removing internal geometry

Tags: modeling

So in the image below there are two circles, how can I remove the internal vertices between them without messing up the outside shape. I'm working on a gun and this is just a simple way to illustrate the issue I'm dealing with. If I where to go in and delete the internal faces it would leave holes on the outside of the object, is there a fast way to get around this?

[image: Red area shows internal geometry]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a release of Blender that is at least 2.77 or newer, then you can use the *edit mode* boolean tools and save a couple steps.

- First select one element of the object in *edit mode* by linked geometry by
  selecting a face, edge, or vertex, and then press <kbd>L</kbd> with
  your mouse hovering over it.
- Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type *Boolean* and select *Mesh: Intersect (Boolean)* from the menu, or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the
  option appears in the menu.
- Next, press <kbd>F6</kbd> to bring up the options for the tool (or
  go to the operator panel in the *toolshelf*) and change the mode to *union*.

[image]

Comment: what if I have 100 cubes joined as one object having overlapping parts? When I switch to edit mode and select all then hit space and choose Intersect Bool then union I get the message "No intersection found", but it works if I select one of the cubes using L then boolean it with the intersected one. Because I have many objects joined as one object, Is there a way to do it without having to select the faces of each cube then running the boolean operation?

Comment: @Tak with that many objects it may be easiest to separate them a bit (`P`>selection) and rejoin them with fewer elements at a time. You could try using the swap option in the operator panel after some booleans if there are missing faces, as it can get a bit messy and may need some manual cleanup with too many objects.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/klpedtksyq1en4q/bool_not_working_properly.blend?dl=0 try this please, once you open the file, switch to edit mode then space and choose intersect boolean and Union, I don't know why for some reason once I do Union bool the whole pose before the selected one gets deleted?

Comment: Could you please advice whenever you can?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the boolean modifier. In order to use it, you first have to seperate the spheres into seperate objects. 
Go into edit mode, select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>P</kbd> and click *By loose parts*.

[image]

You now have 2 seperate spheres. Go back to object mode, select one of the objects and add a boolean modifier.

[image]

Select the other object under the *object* drop-down menu and change *operation* to *union*.

[image]

Do the same thing for the other sphere.

Now you will have two objects, one for the two spheres combined and one for just one as shown below:

[image]
[image]

Select the object which has both spheres and Apply the modifier by clicking on *Apply*.

[image]

Now delete the other object of just one sphere by selecting it, and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

And will now have an object with the shape of both spheres combined, but without the interior geometry as shown below:

[image]