# Remove intersections between many objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have a bunch of objects in my scene that are intersecting each other. Is there any way, without creating a million boolean modifiers on each, to remove all mesh intersections in my scene?

[image: Sort of what my scene looks like]

Maybe there's a script to apply a bunch of booleans to every object?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71687/removing-internal-geometry and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71687/removing-internal-geometry Boolean on all that large amount of possible comninations is a recipe for disaster

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Ok... any other ideas then?

Answer (score 12):

You may use a ***Direct Union*** of a ***BoolTool*** add on.
[image]

Activate the add on in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

Select all the spheres with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type *direct union*.
[image]

If you want to separate each object use ***Linked Flat Faces*** option.
[image]

Select one face of the *sphere*, go to *Select*-->*Linked Flat Faces* (or use a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcut). Increase the *Sharpness* value in a *Tool Shelf*. Then press <kbd>P</kbd>-->*Selection* to separete the selection.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any way that I can keep each object separate?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: That's great! But I kind of need the objects to be solid. That's why I was going with the idea of using multiple boolean modifiers. My idea is to subtract the intersection from both objects, if that makes sense. Like this: http://imgur.com/nEH1aNV but without the painstaking hassle of boole intersecting, duplicating, scaling, and the boole differencing both of them from the intersection for each object. This would probably be easier in a more procedural environment like houdini, but I'll be honest, I don't have that kind of money lying around to just throw at software companies lol

Comment: I guess it isn't possible without doing it manually in a very time consuming way. Consider hiring a talented python coder :). Also try to ask another question about how to do it by scripting.