# How to join 2 objects what way?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

My question isn't really about a problem I'm having but me trying to avoid problems in the future.

So, I am modelling an armoured vehicle for a computer game and all of the handles and other details on the hull were made as separate objects, I've already joined some by selecting them and doing Crtl+J but this doesn't like the meshes in any way. However it not linking the meshes is a good thing as it prevents the resource count from going up but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this?

The main problem I can think of is when in a bit I want to UV-unwrap it that it won't do it as I want as the meshes aren't connected and this I can mark seams etc?

Any input on this would be most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I think if Ctrl+j u dont need then make boolean as union operation

Comment: Yea I know about the boolean, that is the way to join the meshes but I don't want to join the meshes if I don't really HAVE to for whatever reason (uv-unwrap?)

Comment: You mean need one object mean time and when need to separate and individual object you can uvwrap it is that so

Comment: No, it all has to come together as one object at the end and the UV map has to be connected as there will be a camouflage pattern that can't just be interrupted everywhere.

Comment: Maybe this one will help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89979/remove-intersections-between-many-objects

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paul but that is what I'm trying to avoid, using a boolean will merge the 2 meshes and thus create a ton of extra verts etc if I add something to what normally just is a flat plane, which I am trying to avoid. Simply joining the objects with crtl+j avoids this but my question is how that will affect the UV map?

Comment: I'm basically trying to avoid to merge the meshes as that means they have to adjust to eachother. Imagine a small flat plane now simply 'resting' on a bigger flat plane (with the bottom face of it deleted), if I merge them the bigger flat plane will have to adjust and create a bunch of verts and edges to merge.